# Anyone else having issues with the weather app?

Tags: jailbreak, ios

So I jail role with the new evasi0n tool and now I can't launch my weather app. Anyone else experiencing similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been noted on a couple of blogs.
The jailbreak screwed up some files. There is a fix which requires you to:

( taken from [cult of mac](http://www.cultofmac.com/214443/heres-how-to-fix-your-ios-weather-app-that-was-broken-by-the-evasion-jailbreak/)

1. Open Cydia and install Open SSH and MobileTerminal
2. Load MobileTerminal and type “su root” (no quotes). Then hit enter.
3. Enter your password. It’s probably “alpine” if you haven’t changed it yet.
4. Copy and paste the following script into MobileTerminal

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   chmod -x /usr/libexec/mobile_installation_proxy
   killall -9 mobile_installation_proxy
   rm /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.LaunchServices-045.csstore
   launchctl stop com.apple.mobile.installd
   launchctl start com.apple.mobile.installd
   while [ ! -f /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist ];
   do
   sleep 1
   done
   while [ ! -f /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.LaunchServices-045.csstore ];
   do
   sleep 1
   done
   sleep 10
   chmod +x /usr/libexec/mobile_installation_proxy
   ```

   sync

reboot
5. Wait for your iPhone to reboot.
6. Have fun, you’re done.
For info on how to jailbreak your iPhone the right way, check out our video.

Read more at http://www.cultofmac.com/214443/heres-how-to-fix-your-ios-weather-app-that-was-broken-by-the-evasion-jailbreak/#xR7kVryBZBXPmMAd.99 
)